# crossfilter and dc.js line chart to plot every data point in ascending/descending order

Tags: d3.js, charts, dc.js, crossfilter

My data consists of simple information for contracts. Simplified each one looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1234567890,
    "district": "districtname",
    "city": "cityname",
    "test": "testnumber",
    "date": "2015-03-15",
    "score": 0.0 - 1.0
}
```

I already have a simple *dc.barChart* for the number of tests per day and a *dc.rowChart* for districts and another one for cities to filter the currently displayed data with crossfilter.

What I need now is a line chart that plots every score of every contract in ascending or descending order. By that I mean that I do not want to group the data by score but simply plot every score on the y-axis and have nothing on the x-axis. Assuming data is plotted in ascending order the resulting picture will be an ever increasing graph. See below:

[image: line chart]

How do I do this with data that lives inside a crossfilter instance, dc.js and d3.js?

Comment: crossfilter.top(Infinity) will give all the selected data(which is filtered) present. From this you'll get the data what is needed to draw line chart. Am I right...??

Comment: with dimenson.top(Infinity) I have access to all data, yes. But how do I use this data to draw a lineChart then? Since dc's lineCharts requires grouping?

Comment: If ID is unique per contract, can't you group on ID and go from there?

Comment: Right, where do I go from there though? How do I tell dc to sort data by score and then plot the score on the y-axis? I think I need more than just a few tips :/

Comment: [chart.ordering](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#orderingorderfunction) ?

Comment: @Ethan: It took me while to figure out *where to go from there*, but finally got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Gordon: Thank you very much for the *ordering* hint, the graph is now in ascending order :)